# Import a couple hundred images and place them side-by side in photoshop

Tags: photoshop, import

I am trying to create a sequence just like this: http://cf.squarespace.com/details/chef-hand-sequence-hires.png

The issue is, my sequence is much longer, 439 frames. I have the PNG files, I just need to merge them to be side-by-side like it is in the link.
I've tried fiddling around with using actions and droplets, but I can't get it to behave like I want. How can I do it?
Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant for photography. Maybe you should ask this at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I seem to remember a tool in Photoshop for creating a contact sheet, somewhere in the File menu, where you can specify the size of the document, how many columns (439) and how many rows (1) you want, and the margin between each image

Answer (score 3):

I don't see photoshop as the right tool for that purpose. [pnmcat](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnmcat.html) from the [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net) package will easily produce such a strip, from an arbitrary number of images.